# Result "Missing Value" with the JavaScript document.getElementById method

Tags: javascript, applescript

I am trying to automate a search and a focusing on the part where the computer types in the search in the search bar. I think all of my syntax is correct but when I run the code, nothing happens and in the applescript result log it says "missing value"..

Here is my code:

```
to inputByID(theId, theValue) --defines the function--
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        open location "https://www.google.com "
        execute javascript " document.getElementById(' " & theId & " ').value = ' " & theValue
    end tell
end inputByID

inputByID("lst-ib", "hi ")
```

Is my syntax wrong or am I missing something? Any help appreciated..

Comment: Share the actual code. Not pseudo code.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal that is applescript

Comment: you are missing a quote after `theValue` i think it should end with `theValue & " ' "`

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense my bad. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me in macOS High Sierra:

```
to inputByID(theId, theValue)
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        open location "https://www.google.com"
        repeat until (loading of active tab of front window is false)
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        tell active tab of front window
            execute javascript "document.getElementById('" & theId & "').value = '" & theValue & "';"
        end tell
    end tell
end inputByID

inputByID("lst-ib", "Hello World!")
```

Aside from the fact that your `execute javascript ...` line of *code* was a bit malformed, you can compare your's to mine for the difference, you also were not telling Google Chrome where the `execute javascript ...` line of *code* was to be executed. Hence, e.g.: `tell active tab of front window`

Additionally, after using an `open location ...` *command*, you also have to wait for the *target* of the `execute javascript ...` line of *code* to exist, hence the use of the `repeat until (loading of active tab of front window is false)` line of *code* after the `open location ...` *command*, and before the `execute javascript ...` line of *code*.

Comment: I am getting the same thing with a button press code: Here is my code  --  execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName(' " & theClass & " ')[' " & elementnum & " '].click();"--

Comment: i am not sure if my syntax is correct since I am not familiar with applescript

Comment: @Athreya Daniel, As my answer solved the original issue, please post anther question with the relevant information and formatted code.

Answer (score 0):

```
" document.getElementById('" & theId & "').value = '" & theValue & "'"
```

Probably you got to remove the spaces before and after `theId`

so that it becomes `('myId')` instead of `(' myId ')`

and also add a quote at the end.

Comment: it gives the same result even with this code. Is there an alternative solution that you know of?