# "missing value" result when automating a buttonclick apple script

Tags: javascript, applescript

Although I have already posted a similar question that has been well answered, I still do not get why this error happens and how to fix it. Here is my code...

```
to ClickNameClass(theClass, elementnum)
    tell application "Google Chrome"
    open location "https://www.google.com"
        tell active tab of front window
            execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName(' " & theClass & " ')[' " & elementnum & " '].click();"
        end tell
    end tell
end ClickNameClass
```

Is this the syntax for an automated button click and if so why is the error coming? Any help appreciated.....

Comment: An example of how you're using the _handler_ would be nice however, that said, I already told you in the other answer that after using an `open location ...` _command_ you have to wait for the target object to be available to receive the `execute javascript ...` _code_ and why I use `repeat until (loading of active tab of front window is false)` between the  `open location ...` _command_ and the `execute javascript ...` _code_. Also your ` `execute javascript ...` _code_ is malformed again, you have spaces that should not be there.

Comment: could you fix the syntax of the execute javasscript in the answer, I am very new to apple script

Comment: `execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & elementnum & "].click();"`

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness I'm adding an answer...

Like [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025760/result-missing-value-with-the-javascript-document-getelementbyid-method), the `execute javascript ...` *code* is malformed, having *spaces* where they do not belong around the `className` as well as having *single-quotes* around the `indexValue` that shouldn't be there.

The following `clickElementByClassName` *handler*, which has been rewritten from what you originally posted, will open the *target URL*, "https://www.google.com" in this instance, wait for the page to load and then click the *Sign In* button on *Google's Home Page*.

```
on clickElementByClassName(thisURL, className, indexValue)
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        open location thisURL
        repeat until (loading of active tab of front window is false)
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        tell active tab of front window
            execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & className & "')[" & indexValue & "].click();"
        end tell
    end tell
end clickElementByClassName


clickElementByClassName("https://www.google.com", "gb_7f gb_Fa gb_Jb", 0)
```

Looking at the Replies pane in Script Editor it shows:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    open location "https://www.google.com"
    get loading of active tab of window 1
        --> true
    get loading of active tab of window 1
        --> true
    get loading of active tab of window 1
        --> true
    get loading of active tab of window 1
        --> false
    execute active tab of window 1 javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('gb_7f gb_Fa gb_Jb')[0].click();"
        --> missing value
end tell

Result:
missing value
```

As you can see the `execute` line of *code* is not processed until the page has finished loading and there are no *spaces* on each side of the `className` or *single-quotes* around the `indexValue` as there would have been using the original coding.

I also removed the hard coding of the `URL` from within the *handler*, thus making it a bit more versatile and reusable.

As you can see the result was `missing value` and in this instance is not a bad thing as in testing I was taken to the *Sign in - Google Accounts* page as desired in this example.